# Microsoft Excel - condense number of rows

Tags: excel, csv

I have a CSV containing over 400,000 eircodes, and using ArcGIS Pro `Generate Near Table` function to calculate the nearest 3 air quality monitors.

In turn, this has generated a new csv of over 1 million rows as each eircode has been triplicated and given a row to each monitor. (see below example)

| ObjectID | Eircode | Easting | Northing | Monitor Name | Monitor Location | Monitor Easting | Monitor Northing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | K67AH57 | 717387.8 | 748192.3 | Swords | Dublin | 718046.6 | 747362 |
| 2 | K67AH57 | 717387.8 | 748192.3 | Dublin Airport | Dublin | ..... | .... |
| 3 | K67AH57 | 717387.8 | 748192.3 | Finglass | Dublin | ..... | .... |
| 4 | H54W283 | 544468 | 752503 | Claremorris | Mayo | ..... | ..... |
| 5 | H54W283 | 544468 | 752503 | Rahoon | Galway | ..... | ..... |
| 6 | H54W283 | 544468 | 752503 | Roscommon | Roscommon | ..... | ..... |

Is there a way, in Microsoft Excel to achieve the below output? As I only want an eircode on a single row and containing all the relevant info.

| ObjectID | Eircode | Easting | Northing | M1_Name | M1_Location | M1_Easting | M1_Northing | M2_Name | M2_Location | M2_Easting | M2_Northing | M3_Name | M3_Location | M3_Easting | M3_Northing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | K67AH57 | 717387.8 | 748192.3 | Swords | Dublin | 718046.6 | 747362 | Dublin Airport | Dublin | ..... | .... | Finglass | Dublin | ..... | .... |
| 2 | H54W283 | 544468 | 752503 | Claremorris | Mayo | ..... | ..... | Rahoon | Galway | ..... | ..... | Roscommon | Roscommon | ..... | ..... |

Comment: You're using the wrong tool. Excel tops out at just over a million rows, and really is terrible with that much data.

Comment: @BigBen I'm not sure what else to use as the file was saved in csv format

Comment: Python, R, take your pick. Note that Excel is *not* CSV. It can work with CSV files, but is most certainly not CSV.

Comment: Or you could consider using Power Query within Excel if you're stuck with that route.

Comment: @BigBen I'm familiar with python, but would have no idea how to script the exact changes I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using Python, and its **DictReader/Writer** classes, which makes working with the headers/columns you need pretty straightforward.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import sys

COMBINED_ROW_TMPL = dict(
    ObjectID=0,
    Eircode='',
    Easting='',
    Northing='',
    M1_Name='',
    M1_Location='',
    M1_Easting='',
    M1_Northing='',
    M2_Name='',
    M2_Location='',
    M2_Easting='',
    M2_Northing='',
    M3_Name='',
    M3_Location='',
    M3_Easting='',
    M3_Northing=''
)

combined_rows = []
with open('input.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    object_id = 0
    last_eircode = ''
    combined_row = {}
    m_i = 0
    for row in reader:
        this_eircode = row['Eircode']

        if this_eircode != last_eircode:
            # A new Eircode, set up combined_row with data that doesn't change
            object_id += 1
            combined_row = dict(COMBINED_ROW_TMPL)  # a clean copy of the template

            combined_row['ObjectID'] = object_id
            combined_row['Eircode']  = this_eircode
            combined_row['Easting']  = row['Easting']
            combined_row['Northing'] = row['Northing']

            m_i = 1  # reset monitor group to first instance (i.e., "M1")
            last_eircode = this_eircode

        # Monitor group
        pfx = f'M{m_i}'
        combined_row[pfx + '_Name']     = row['Monitor Name']
        combined_row[pfx + '_Location'] = row['Monitor Location']
        combined_row[pfx + '_Easting']  = row['Monitor Easting']
        combined_row[pfx + '_Northing'] = row['Monitor Northing']

        if m_i == 3:
            combined_rows.append(combined_row)  # only append once per monitor group

        m_i += 1


with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, COMBINED_ROW_TMPL.keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(combined_rows)
```

When I run that with your sample as **input.csv**

```
ObjectID,Eircode,Easting,Northing,Monitor Name,Monitor Location,Monitor Easting,Monitor Northing
1,K67AH57,717387.8,748192.3,Swords,Dublin,718046.6,747362
2,K67AH57,717387.8,748192.3,Dublin Airport,Dublin,.....,....
3,K67AH57,717387.8,748192.3,Finglass,Dublin,.....,....
4,H54W283,544468,752503,Claremorris,Mayo,.....,.....
5,H54W283,544468,752503,Rahoon,Galway,.....,.....
6,H54W283,544468,752503,Roscommon,Roscommon,.....,.....
```

I get the following for **output.csv**:

```
ObjectID,Eircode,Easting,Northing,M1_Name,M1_Location,M1_Easting,M1_Northing,M2_Name,M2_Location,M2_Easting,M2_Northing,M3_Name,M3_Location,M3_Easting,M3_Northing
1,K67AH57,717387.8,748192.3,Swords,Dublin,718046.6,747362,Dublin Airport,Dublin,.....,....,Finglass,Dublin,.....,....
2,H54W283,544468,752503,Claremorris,Mayo,.....,.....,Rahoon,Galway,.....,.....,Roscommon,Roscommon,.....,.....
```

Comment: Amazing!!! You're a lifesaver - this done exactly as I needed and was easily followed for any modifications!

Answer (score 1):

BigBen is correct about Excel, but this piqued my interest, and if you're only doing this occasionally... so I just knocked up this extremely simplistic (And likely error riddled) code. Paste the below into a code module in VBA in Excel (Step though with F8). Copy data into Sheet1 and it will process to Sheet2. Start with a few hundred rows and see how long it takes (watch the Status Bar progress in bottom left of Excel window) ... I'm guessing too long to be practical for 1M rows.(Can be sped up probably 10 times more by working entirely in Arrays/memory, if practical).
So, for what it's worth:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ToOneLine()

Dim CurrEir As String
Dim PreviousEir As String
Dim EirIndex As Integer
Dim RowIndex As Long
Dim WriteRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

'Debug.Print Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count 'result of this put in as Maximum Array size in the line below
Const MaxArraySize = 1048576
Dim ArrayEir(1 To MaxArraySize, 1 To 16)

LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

        WriteRow = 0
        PreviousEir = ""
        RowIndex = 1
        
    Do While EirIndex <= 3

        CurrEir = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 2), Cells(RowIndex, 2))
        
        If PreviousEir <> CurrEir Then
            EirIndex = 1
            WriteRow = WriteRow + 1
        ElseIf PreviousEir = CurrEir Then
            EirIndex = EirIndex + 1
        End If
        PreviousEir = CurrEir
        
        ArrayEir(WriteRow, 1) = WriteRow                                        '"Line Number"
        ArrayEir(WriteRow, 2) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 2), Cells(RowIndex, 2))  'Eircode
        ArrayEir(WriteRow, 3) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 3), Cells(RowIndex, 3))  'Easting
        ArrayEir(WriteRow, 4) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 4), Cells(RowIndex, 4))  'Northing
        If EirIndex = 1 Then
            ArrayEir(WriteRow, 5) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 5), Cells(RowIndex, 5))  'M1_Name
            ArrayEir(WriteRow, 6) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 6), Cells(RowIndex, 6))  'M1_Location
            ArrayEir(WriteRow, 7) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 7), Cells(RowIndex, 7))  'M1_Easting
            ArrayEir(WriteRow, 8) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 8), Cells(RowIndex, 8))  'M1_Northing
        ElseIf EirIndex = 2 Then
            ArrayEir(WriteRow, 9) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 5), Cells(RowIndex, 5))  'M2_Name
            ArrayEir(WriteRow, 10) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 6), Cells(RowIndex, 6))  'M2_Location
            ArrayEir(WriteRow, 11) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 7), Cells(RowIndex, 7))  'M2_Easting
            ArrayEir(WriteRow, 12) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 8), Cells(RowIndex, 8))  'M2_Northing
        ElseIf EirIndex = 3 Then
            ArrayEir(WriteRow, 13) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 5), Cells(RowIndex, 5))  'M3_Name
            ArrayEir(WriteRow, 14) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 6), Cells(RowIndex, 6))  'M3_Location
            ArrayEir(WriteRow, 15) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 7), Cells(RowIndex, 7))  'M3_Easting
            ArrayEir(WriteRow, 16) = Range(Cells(RowIndex, 8), Cells(RowIndex, 8))  'M3_Northing
        End If

        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & RowIndex & " in " & LastRow & " of possibly " & MaxArraySize
        
        
        RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
    Loop
    
        Application.StatusBar = False

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(ArrayEir, 1), UBound(ArrayEir, 2))).Value = ArrayEir

End Sub
```